# Is there any way to programatically check running VUser count while load test is in progress?

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner

I want to programatically check running VUser count in LoadRunner while a test is running. Is there any API exists where I can get this?

Thanks!

Comment: You will have to be more specific with "in LoadRunner". Do you mean in Controller or in PC or on LG? Please describe your scenario in detail and also mention the LoadRunner version number.

Comment: context please.....    Will you also be trying to check other statistics?

Comment: @Buzzy...Thank you for your response. I mean to say LoadRunner Controller. We are using 11.52 version. Purpose: We are building one alert system which will be used during performance testing. We will correlate running VUser counts with other application data and if anything is wrong(like SLA is being violated), we can send alert to the concerned people. With my limited knowledge in LoadRunner, I could not found anything which can get me the running VUser count during the test. Hope this helps. Thanks!

Comment: @JamesPulley...please see my previous response. No, I do not want to check other statistics. Only VUser count will be sufficient(for now). :)

Comment: By Running Vusers count, do you mean Graph? If yes, then you can find running vusers graph in -> Run Section -> "Available Graphs".(Its a real-time graph showing No. of Vusers running at particular time).

Comment: @VishalCruise Yeah, I can see the graph. What I am asking is that if there is any way to get those number programatically? Any idea?